# How to calculate formatted String such as '1,000,000*2' in java

Tags: java, excel, string, algorithm, apache-poi

I'm making a program that extracts text from cells which contains information about details of price  and text from cells which contains information about price in excel file and then compare them.

I successfully extract them with apache poi, but I have no idea about ***how to calculate text from cells which contains information about details of price.***

Those texts has some pattern as below.

- \3,000*641
- Deposit(\10,000*105)
- Beef(\20,900*3) + Coke 1.25L(\3,000*2)
- Chicken(\22,900*3) - Discount(\39,400)

I think someone would recommend using the ***formula evaluation*** in apache poi. Unfortunately, celltype of cells which contains information about details of price is ***not FORMULA but STRING.***

I hope you show me some code which calculate those formatted text!

Comment: You need to get the content of the cell, split it up into numbers, text and Signs. Then you need to cast the numbers to Double and calculate... You can so this by using different methods.. create it in your own or think about using a DSL parser like AntLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can extract the expressions and format them to remove commas and such (i.e. `.replace(",", "")`), then you can run the code in a `ScriptEngine` to automatically parse and execute the expression.

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
// evaluate JavaScript code from String
Object x = engine.eval("100 * 3");
```

Depending on what String you pass to the eval method is what kind of Object it will return.